# Stylus background image not showing

Tags: webpack, stylus

I want to load an image as a `background-image` but failed. I believe this has something to do with my webpack.config.js. Here my stylus code

```
& .box
    background url("/images/center1.jpg") no-repeat right center 
    -webkit-background-size cover
    -moz-background-size cover
    -o-background-size cover
    background-size cover
```

and here is my webpack

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]!postcss!stylus-loader?resolve url'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|otf)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'url-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=8192'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader:  'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader:  'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass?resolve url'
            }
        ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here and speculate that `& .box` should be written without the space: `&.box`.